Book I read in early 2000s (but felt older) about three orphan girls, red, blonde, brunette, forced to do magic
It was a full length novel. Three girls (who might be related) come to live with a woman (who might be an aunt). The girls each have a different colour hair, and that is why they have been collected by the woman - she is a witch, and only when the three girl's hair touches can she extract their magic. She often violently forces their heads together. In the end, the girls realise that since they can do magic when their hair touches, they can undo the spells of the witch (?and her coven?)

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  When did you read this?

In or before 2006. I feel like the cover art was the three girls - drawn, not a photo - just thier heads floating with their hair plaited together, or pulled together. The look on one face was sad, but resigned (I think you could only see one face)
